# Switching between profiles to manage multiple implementations on one spring interface

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to use different implementations of a Spring Interface with different profiles. I have multiple modules that have code in different modules. Interface and 2 implementations are in a module and the class that calls the Interface is in a different module. My code is something like this:

from module1:

```
public class FirstService {

    @Autowired
    private Interface interfaceImplementation;
}
```

from module2:

```
public interface Interface {

}
```

```
@Service
@Profile("develop")
public class InterfaceImpl1 implements Interface {

}
```

```
@Service
@Profile("test")
public class InterfaceImpl2 implements Interface {

}
```

when I start my application, the application failed to start with the following error:

```
Field interface in FirstService required a bean of type Interface that could not be found
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you start your application? Do you enable one of the profiles when starting the app?

Comment: I have <properties> <spring.profiles.active>develop</spring.profiles.active> </properties> in my pom file. I tried starting through eclipse and from command line by this command: java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=develop myApplication.jar. It fails whichever way I try. Thanks.

Comment: I have the develop profile set as default in my pom. Thanks      
<profile>
         <id>develop</id>
         <activation>
             <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <properties>
             <spring.profiles.active>develop</spring.profiles.active>
         </properties>
     </profile>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the base package of the interface, implementations that are in a separate module to the @ComponentScan in the application.

Answer (score 0):

While on you application is started up on your default profile so there will be no bean of type "Interface" because in your code Implementation of "Interace" will be created by spring only if your app is started in "develop" or "test" profile. there are number of ways to set the profile in spring and easiest way set it as System parameter or environmental variable

Eg of setting as System parameter

`-Dspring.profiles.active=develop` or  `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` (according which environment you are running)

Eg of setting as environmental variable

linux:- `export spring_profiles_active=true`
windows:- `set spring_profiles_active=true`

Comment: As mentioned above develop profile is set as default in my pom file. When I start my app from eclipse, I added an environment variable spring.profiles.active by clicking on 'Run Configurations' and selecting the application.